# Merge child Map to Parent map comparing by key Java8

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap, java-stream

I have these classes

```
class Student {
  private int s_id;
  private String address;
  private List<Book> books;
}

class Book {
  private int s_id;
  private String author;
  private String book_id;
}
```

Now I have `Map<Integer, Student>` and `Map<Integer, List<Book>>` and based on **s_id** I want to merge both the maps.

So one student can have multiple books and I want **list of all students with their number of books**.

```
Map<Integer,Student> students;
Map<Integer,List<Book>> books 
students.keySet().stream().map(s-> students.get(s).setBooks(books.get(x)))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: So, would you please show us the code you have written so far to solve this?

Comment: I was just thinking if I have `Map<Integer,Student> students`, `Map<Integer,List<Book>> books` then using java 8 stream api something like
`students.keySet().stream().map(s-> students.get(s).setBooks(books.get(x))).collect(Collectors.toList());`
I just started learning java 8 stream api and need help to construct this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain the structure of both Map ? What represents the key in both ?

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.

```java
for(int id : students.keySet()) {

   students.get(id).setBooks(books.get(id));

}
```